# Xamarin Forms UWP specifying button width request with an effect

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

I would like to specify the width of a Xamarin.Forms.Button with an effect in UWP, something like:

```
protected override void OnAttached()
{
    if (VisualElement is Xamarin.Forms.Button buttonControl)
    {
        buttonControl.WidthRequest = 40;
        buttonControl.BorderWidth = 1;
    }
}
```

VisualElement is an invalid type. What goes in its place? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Xamarin Forms UWP specifying button width request with an effect

In Xamarin effect class, the attached control is referenced with [`Element`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.effect.element?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Effect_Element) property but not `VisualElement`, please edit your code like the following and you will get forms button on `OnAttached` method.

```
protected override void OnAttached()
{
    if (Element is Xamarin.Forms.Button buttonControl)
    {
        buttonControl.WidthRequest = 40;
        buttonControl.BorderWidth = 1;
    }      
}
```